# How to pass src url from html tag in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an following html

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/974995848/?label=CZ0KCLjDuSQQiIP10AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
```

From this how can i pass an url from src tag using ruby. I expect this result `"http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/974995848/?label=CZ0KCLjDuSQQiIP10AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"`

Comment: You mean `parse` an `url`?

Answer (score 0):

If it is whole string to parse you can use `/src="([^"]+)"/i` regexp to extract this. If you have whole page then read about Nokogiri.